# how to convert pine script v5 code to mql5 code?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, mql5

I have this code in pine script 5:

```
myfunc(myinput,myinput1)=>
    first = ta.atr(myinput1)
    up = hl2 + first
    dn = hl2 - first
    upper = 0.,lower = 0.
    upper := myinput[1] < upper[1] ? math.min(up,upper[1]) : up
    lower := myinput[1] > lower[1] ? math.max(dn,lower[1]) : dn
    second = 0,max = 0.,min = 0.
    second := myinput > upper ? 1 : myinput < lower ? 0 : second[1]
    third = second == 1 ? lower : upper
    max := ta.cross(myinput,third) ? math.max(myinput,max[1]) : second == 1 ? math.max(myinput,max[1]) : third
    min := ta.cross(myinput,third) ? math.min(myinput,min[1]) : second == 0 ? math.min(myinput,min[1]) : third
    math.avg(max,min)
firstcall = myfunc(close,5)
secondcall = myfunc(close,10)
if ta.crossover(firstcall,secondcall)
    strategy.entry("buy",strategy.long,contracts)
if ta.crossunder(firstcall,secondcall)
    strategy.entry("sell",strategy.short,contracts)
```

and code above is working fine.there is a function that called 2 time in every candle and return 2 different value.after that, if 2 value has a cross in 2 consecutive candle, we open a buy or sell position. i'd try to convert this code to mql5 language and wrote code below:

```
double upper[2],lower[2]= {0,0};
double second[2]= {0,0};
double max[2],min[2]= {0,0};
double third[2]= {0,0};

CTrade trade;
CPositionInfo position;
int tp=10000;
int sl=10000;
MqlDateTime CandleTime;
datetime NewTime=0;
double firstcall[2]= {0,0};
double secondcall[2]= {0,0};
void OnTick()
  {
   if(NewTime!=iTime(NULL,0,0))
     {
      TimeCurrent(CandleTime);
      firstcall[1]=firstcall[0];
      firstcall[0]=myfunc(1,5);
      secondcall[1]=secondcall[0];
      secondcall[0]=myfunc(1,10);
      upper[1]=upper[0];
      lower[1]=lower[0];
      second[1]=second[0];
      max[1]=max[0];
      min[1]=min[0];
      third[1]=third[0];
      if(firstcall[0]>secondcall[0]
         &&firstcall[1]<secondcall[1]
        {
         trade.Buy(0.01,NULL,SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(),SYMBOL_ASK),SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(),SYMBOL_ASK)-sl*Point(),SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(),SYMBOL_BID)+tp*Point());
        }
      if(firstcall[0]<secondcall[0]
         &&firstcall[1]>secondcall[1]
        {
         trade.Sell(0.01,NULL,SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(),SYMBOL_BID),SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(),SYMBOL_BID)+sl*Point(),SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(),SYMBOL_ASK)-tp*Point());
        }
      NewTime=iTime(NULL,0,0);
     }
   return;
  }
double myfunc(int myinput,int myinput1)
  {
   double PriceArray[];
   ArraySetAsSeries(PriceArray,true);
   double ATRDef=iATR(NULL,0,myinput1);
   CopyBuffer(ATRDef,0,0,3,PriceArray);
   double first=NormalizeDouble(PriceArray[0],5);
   double hl2=(iHigh(NULL,0,myinput)+iLow(NULL,0,myinput))/2;
   double up=hl2+first;
   double dn=hl2+first;
   upper[0]=0;
   lower[0]=0;
   upper[0]=iClose(NULL,0,myinput+1)<upper[1] ? MathMin(up,upper[1]) : up;
   lower[0]=iClose(NULL,0,myinput+1)>lower[1] ? MathMax(dn,lower[1]) : dn;
   second[0]=0;
   max[0]=0;
   min[0]=0;
   second[0]=iClose(NULL,0,myinput)>upper[0] ? 1 : iClose(NULL,0,myinput)<lower[0] ? 0 : second[1];
   third[0]= second[0]==1 ? lower[0] : upper[0];
   bool cross=(iClose(NULL,0,myinput+1)<third[1] && iClose(NULL,0,myinput)>third[0])||(iClose(NULL,0,myinput+1)>third[1] && iClose(NULL,0,myinput)<third[0]);
   max[0]= cross ? MathMax(iClose(NULL,0,myinput),max[1]) : second[0]==1 ? MathMax(iClose(NULL,0,myinput),max[1]) : third[0];
   min[0]= cross ? MathMin(iClose(NULL,0,myinput),min[1]) : second[0]==0 ? MathMin(iClose(NULL,0,myinput),min[1]) : third[0];
   return (max[0]+min[0])/2;
  }
```

but it doesn't work and doesn't get neither a single position.

Actually the cross never happens in mql5 code.

I made an array for each variable because I want to simulate series in pine script, but I think we need just 2 last value of every variable so I made arrays with just length of 2.

Am I thinking right? What's wrong with code?